# How do you loop a "while" statement in order to make the user repeat their input until a valid answer is typed?

Tags: c#

I have a simple command prompt that asks the user basic questions for them to answer. One of them involves taking two numbers that the user provided and asking whether to add, subtract, multiply, or divide them. What I am stuck on is how the program handles invalid answers. What I want to happen is for the program to ask the user to try again if they type anything besides "add", "subtract", "multiply", or "divide", but I have only gotten as far as asking the question once then closing.

The closest I have gotten was to have several "while" statements that said while the response is not equal to add, subtract, multiply, or divide, ask to try again. After the while statements, I included if statements that would perform the corresponding operation based on what the user inputted.
Here is my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Would you like me to add, subtract, multiply, or divide these numbers?");

        var response = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        double addTotal = num1 + num2;
        double subtractTotal = num1 - num2;
        double multiplyTotal = num1 * num2;
        double divideTotal = num1 / num2;

        while ((response != "add") || (response != "Add") || (response != "subtract") || (response != "Subtract") || (response != "multiply") || (response != "Multiply") || (response != "divide") || (response != "Divide"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I didn't understand that, could you try again?");
            response = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        if (response == "add")
        {
            Console.Beep();
            Console.WriteLine("Good choice! I will now add these numbers.");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine(userName+ ", your total is "+addTotal+ "!");
        }
        if (response == "Add")
        {
            Console.Beep();
            Console.WriteLine("Good choice! I will now add these numbers.");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine(userName+ ", your total is "+addTotal+ "!");
        }
        if (response == "subtract")
        {
            Console.Beep();
            Console.WriteLine("Good choice! I will now subtract these numbers.");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine(userName+ ", your total is "+subtractTotal+ "!");
        }
        if (response == "Subtract")
        {
            Console.Beep();
            Console.WriteLine("Good choice! I will now subtract these numbers.");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine(userName+ ", your total is "+subtractTotal+ "!");
        }
        if (response == "multiply")
        {
            Console.Beep();
            Console.WriteLine("Good choice! I will now multiply these numbers.");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine(userName+ ", your total is "+multiplyTotal+ "!");
        }
        if (response == "Multiply")
        {
            Console.Beep();
            Console.WriteLine("Good choice! I will now multiply these numbers.");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine(userName+ ", your total is "+multiplyTotal+ "!");
        }    
        if (response == "divide")
        {
            Console.Beep();
            Console.WriteLine("Good choice! I will now divide these numbers.");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine(userName+ ", your total is "+divideTotal+ "!");
        }
        if (response == "Divide")
        {
            Console.Beep();
            Console.WriteLine("Good choice! I will now divide these numbers.");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine(userName+ ", your total is "+divideTotal+ "!");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

I know it's messy, but I'm new to this and I'm not sure how to condense it.

When I try this, it always just asks me to try again even when inputting the correct terms.

Comment: Ok so you while condition is "do this as long as response is not add or Add or etc."
But when your response is add it isnt Add. Therefore your while condition fires.

Comment: ^^ "... condition fires" .. **always**.

Comment: Also rethink your UX choices. No user in the world wants to type out "subtract". Give them a choice like "Choose Add, Subtract, Multiply or Divide ('a'|'s'|'m'|'d')" or 1,2,3,4 ... single key press choices.

Comment: And if you need to compare strings case insensitively, do so: [How to compare strings in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings#case-insensitive-ordinal-comparisons)

Comment: `while (response != "add" || response != "Add") { … }` – so if you enter "add", it is not equal to "Add" (your loop will run) and if you enter "Add", it is not equal to "add" (and your loop will run). That should really be `&&` and not `||` ([De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive done a bit of clean up, as well as correcting the mistake whilst trying to stay as close to your source code as possible.

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Would you like me to add, subtract, multiply, or divide these numbers?");

        var response = Console.ReadLine();
        string addString = "add";
        string subString = "subtract";
        string mulString = "multiply";
        string divString = "divide";
        double addTotal = num1 + num2;
        double subtractTotal = num1 - num2;
        double multiplyTotal = num1 * num2;
        double divideTotal = num1 / num2;
        string resString;
        double result;

        while (!(addString.Equals(response, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || subString.Equals(response, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || mulString.Equals(response, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || divString.Equals(response, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I didn't understand that, could you try again?");
            response = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        if (addString.Equals(response, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            resString = addString;
            result = addTotal;
        }
        else if (subString.Equals(response, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            resString = subString;
            result = subtractTotal;
        }
        else if (mulString.Equals(response, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            resString = mulString;
            result = multiplyTotal;
        }   
        else
        {
            resString = divString;
            result = divideTotal;
        }
        
        Console.Beep();
        Console.WriteLine("Good choice! I will now "+resString+" these numbers.");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine(userName+ ", your total is "+result+ "!");
        
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Im also going to give you this, if you want something more readable

```cs
//An extra method for you to add, to make it more readable
public bool EqualString(string root, string compare)
{
    return String.Equals(root, compare, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}


//Correction for your code
Console.WriteLine("Would you like me to add, subtract, multiply, or divide these numbers?");

        var response = Console.ReadLine();
        string resString;
        double result;

        while (!(EqualString("add", response) || EqualString("subtract", response) || EqualString("multiply", response) || EqualString("divide", response)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I didn't understand that, could you try again?");
            response = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        if (EqualString("add", response))
        {
            resString = "add";
            result = num1 + num2;
        }
        else if (EqualString("subtract", response))
        {
            resString = "subtract";
            result = num1 - num2;
        }
        else if (EqualString("multiply", response))
        {
            resString = "multiply";
            result = num1 * num2;
        }   
        else
        {
            resString = "divide";
            result = num1 / num2;
        }
        
        Console.Beep();
        Console.WriteLine("Good choice! I will now "+resString+" these numbers.");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine(userName+ ", your total is "+result+ "!");
        
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: _"response = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()).ToLower();"_ - absolutely not. ToLower _will_ fail in international environments. You _can_ compare strings case insensitively if you know the API. It should be used.

Comment: @Fildor  fair enough i just wahnted to make things more readable. And well I do not think that this will be used in international enviroments/enviroments where .ToLower will make trouble. This right here is a simple biginners programm, so .ToLower can still be used.

Comment: It's an anti-pattern that should be discouraged. Just like writing plane text passwords to a db.

Comment: @Fildor  Well yes but this is someone new to this. For the sake of simplicity I feel like they can use this.

Comment: What is more complicated about the _correct_ API (which I linked to in comment to the question) ?

Comment: @Fildor  is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Basically yes. It's more code (count of chars), but it tells you exactly what you are doing.

Comment: `Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());` - One last thing: this does not make sense. `ReadLine` returns a `string` already.

Comment: @Fildor  oh yeah totally overlooked that during correction

Answer (score 0):

While your code will work fine, I suspect the point of this sort of exercise is to learn to think about a problem abstractly and break it down into smaller functions. This generally makes code easier to read and maintain.

If I were to talk to you over coffee about the program, what would you say is the first thing it has to do? **Get a command from the user**. So why not write a function that does that?

```
enum Command { Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide }

static Command GetCommandFromUser()
{
    WriteMessageToUser("Please enter a command.");
    while (true)
    {
        var text = ReadStringFromUser();
        var ok = Enum.TryParse(text,  ignoreCase: true, out Command command);
        if (ok) return command;
        WriteMessageToUser("I didn't understand that, could you try again?");
    }   
}
```

For now I think the input and output will come from the `Console`, but I might want to change that later, so I will abstractify those actions into expressions that I can later change in one place if needed.

```
static string ReadStringFromUser() => Console.ReadLine();

static void WriteMessageToUser(string text) => Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Then you'd call `GetCommandFromUser` from your main program, along with functions that perform the other steps.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var command = GetCommandFromUser();
    ExecuteCommand(command);
    ShowTheTotal();
}
```

There are many ways you can implement `ExecuteCommand`. The `if` statements you are using are fine. You could also use `switch` `case`. Or if you want to be very extensible you could implement each command as its own function and put them in a dictionary.

```
static void Add()
{
}
static void Subtract()
{
}
static void Multiply()
{
}
static void Divide()
{
}

static Dictionary<Command,Action> _dispatchTable = new Dictionary<Command,Action>
{
    { Command.Add, Program.Add },
    { Command.Subtract, Program.Subtract },
    { Command.Multiply, Program.Multiply },
    { Command.Divide, Program.Divide }
};

static void ExecuteCommand(Command command)
{
    WriteMessageToUser($"Good choice! I will now {command.ToString().ToLower()} these numbers.");
    _dispatchTable[command]();
}
```

You could obviously go very deep with this if the point is to try things out. On the other hand, in a very practical sense, all of this is overkill and the way you coded this program is probably fine.